# How to bind property of one control to another?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF control (ControlA) which references another control (ControlB) like so:

```
<Grid>
    <controls:ControlB x:Name="ControlB"  />         
    <my:DataGrid 
        x:Name="dataGridBackup" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <my:DataGrid.Columns>
            <my:DataGridCheckBoxColumn 
                Header="Connectable" 
                Binding="{Binding Connectable}"  />
        </my:DataGrid.Columns>
    </my:DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Now in ControlB I have a button and i want to bind the IsEnabled property to the Connectable column of my Grid on controlA.

I can get it working when i have the controls on the same page but not in the aboce scenario. I tried with

```
<Button 
    IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=dataGridBackup, Path=SelectedItem.Connectable}">
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Button inside `ControlB` has no normal way to know what's outside the control `ControlB`. One possible solution is to add boolean dependency property to `ControlB` like `IsConnectable`. In XAML of control `ControlA`, bind the property to `dataGridBackup` with path, like you did. In XAML of control `ControlB`, bind the button's `IsEnabled` property to `IsConnectable` of `ControlB`.